# Indentation problems in Python when using other people's files

Tags: python, tkinter, indentation

I downloaded the source code for the famed book "Python Tkinter" by Grayson from the [suggested source](http://www.manning.com/grayson) and loaded the first file in my Python 3.3 editor. Every line gave an indentation error. I thought it maybe a tab/indent conflict so backspaced every line then pressed enter to convert the tab to an indent – line by line and it cured the problem!

**Question:** Is there a way to remove tabs and convert them to indents without having to backspace then enter every line?

Comment: Sublime text editor can do that in a whim! If you are using IDLE, it has find and replace feature as well.

Comment: Open it with vim.  Then do `:%s/\t/    /g`

Comment: How do you do it in sublime?

Comment: @TimothyLawman I have given an answer, with a screenshot. Take a look

Comment: It was a superb reply and have ticked the Answer to give you a point!People don't seem to  like the question but the answer is in  my stackoverflow database and my students will benefit!I will get sublime on the system.

Comment: @TimothyLawman thanks for that up! But you should mark the answer as accepted too (the green tick!), as you said it helped you :)

Comment: Sorry man , green ticked! Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using IDLE, do these:

- do a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to invoke `Replace`.
- Check the `Regular expression`
- In the `Find` text field, type `\t`
- In the `Replace with` text field, type four spaces
- Click replace all

You can do it with sublime very easily. Look at the lower right corner. There are two buttons, the one on the left is the one you need. Click on it. It will bring up a menu. Click "Convert Indentation to spaces" from the menu. Done!

[image: snapshot]

Comment: Also in some IDE there is a button for this. For example in PyCharm you can just use `Reformat Code` and it will solve your problem

Comment: @GáborErdős yes. It is such a trifle thing! I think apart from notepad in windows, every text editor in the world can do that with ease.